# Crash when manipulating a simple Core Data object

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data, ios

I'm diving into iOS development and I have a few questions about manipulating a simple Core Data object that I created in Xcode.  After using the object editor, here's the class that Xcode generated for me...

```
@interface Alarm :  NSManagedObject  
{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * Enabled;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * Label;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * Snooze;

@end

@implementation Alarm 

@dynamic Enabled;
@dynamic Label;
@dynamic Snooze;

@end
```

Here's a code snipped where I try and create an `Alarm` object that I plan to add to my ManagedObjectContext...

```
- (void)saveAlarm:(id)sender {

    Alarm *alarm = [[Alarm alloc] init];

    alarm.Label = [NSString stringWithString:txtLabel.text];    
    alarm.Snooze = [NSNumber numberWithBool:switchSnooze.on];
    alarm.Enabled = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

    [addAlarmDelegate insertNewAlarm:alarm];
    [alarm release]; 
}
```

My code crashes the first time I try and assign a value to one of the properties of alarm, on the line...

```
alarm.Label = [NSString stringWithString:txtLabel.text];
```

with the following crash message in the console...

```
reason: '-[Alarm setLabel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5e33640
```

what am I missing here?

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Comment: As a general style point, I'd avoid capitalizing your properties...

Comment: xcode capitalized them when it generated them, not me

Comment: Xcode capitalized them because you have caps in your entities I suspect.  You should avoid that as well.

Comment: hi @BeachRunnerJoe have u developed a alarm application.Because i am also developing an alarm application but i dont want to use localnotification instead i want to display a custom page when my alarm rings.Please help me in solving my problem. i have stuck on this .Please can u provide me some sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not allocate and init an NSManagedObject-based object directly. You should use

```
[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Alarm" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
```

It might be the reason for it not to work. Because it is usually pretty straight forward to make it work.

The documentation says:

> If you instantiate a managed object
>   directly, you must call the designated
>   initializer
>   (initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:).

And in initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:'s documentation:

> Important:  This method is the
>   designated initializer for
>   NSManagedObject. You must not
>   initialize a managed object simply by
>   sending it init.

Comment: You should actually use `+[NSEntityDescription insertEntityForName: inManagedObjectContext:]` instead.  It is unnecessary to use the `-init...` method directly.

Answer (score 4):

I would look into using mogenerator:

http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/

The command line to run it is:

```
mogenerator -m MyAwesomeApp.xcdatamodel -O Classes
```

Whatever directory you put after -O is where the produced classes go.  The great thing is it has simpler methods to create new manage objects in a context, and also produces a class you can customize (adding your own methods) that do not get removed even when you regenerate objects from your model.

Much simpler than using the XCode object generation.

Comment: Whoever marked this as spam has no idea what mogenerator does.  This is a perfectly relevant suggestion for auto-generating code corresponding to a Core Data entity.